# General form for differentiable function satisfying mean-value property?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f(x,y)$ be a differentiable and integrable function defined in a domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\forall(x_0,y_0)\in D$, $C$ is a circle in $D$ with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and arbitrary radius $r$. We are given that

$\displaystyle f(x_0,y_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C f(x,y)d\theta$

Equivalently, the function value at a point is average of values at circle with center at that point, and arbitrary radius such that circle is fully inside the domain $D$.

What notable observations can we make about $f(x,y)$? I know that if $f(x,y)$ is harmonic, it satisfies the mean-value property, but I'm interested in the converse.

Also curious about higher dimension generalization.

Comment: Even if you weaken your assumption to f being continuous only, the converse is still true. The reason is essentially because the Dirichlet problem for a disk has a solution (i.e given a continuous function on the boundary of a disk, you can extend to a function which is continuous on the whole closed disk and harmonic on the interior); then you just have to apply the maximum modulus principle carefully.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich corrected.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for the observation. The major question is still pending:
what happens when we allow non-harmonic solutions?

Comment: @LewisParker If your $f$ is continuous and has the mean-value property, then it is guaranteed to be harmonic, so I'm not sure what you mean by "allow non-harmonic solutions".